# Measure the concentration of lactose in dairy products

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration

I would like to measure the concentration of lactose in various dairy products : milk, cheese, yoghourt...

How is it done in labs ?
How can I do that using cheap equipments ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for economical methods then you have the option of titration and spectrophotometry. See this paper by Folin [THE DETERMINATION OF LACTOSE J. Biol. Chem. 1918, 33, 521-524](http://www.jbc.org/content/33/3/521.citation). The titration is based on the reducing ability of lactose.

Another reliable titrimetric method can be seen in this paper by Hites, [Determination of Lactose in Milk Products J. Anal. Chem. 1949, 21(8), 993-995](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac60032a035).